# TeXlipse error while building workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

We seem to have a strange problem at the moment with TeXlipse. I have just recently setup a project on my machine with folders that contain chapters of a book. I then put everything under source control and earlier today tried to build the same project on another machine. When I first open the project and save it everything builds ok and I have no problems. However once I add a new latex file in the project in that machine I get the following dialog box:

> Building workspace has encountered a problem
>
> Errors occured during the build
>
> Errors running builder 'Latex Builder' on project.

If I do the same things on my machine I get no errors. Does anyone have an idea as to why we get the errors above on one machine and not other? Eclipse installation is the same, we have the same version of MikTex 2.9 and the same packages.

The error that comes up is:

```
Errors running builder 'Latex Builder' on project 'doc_help'.
Resource '/doc_help/tmp/main.aux' already exists.
Resource '/doc_help/tmp/main.aux' already exists.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please, open the Error log (Window/Show view/Other...), and find the detailed error message with an exception trace. That would make it easier to guess the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ok cool I have added the error on my original edit above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got similar problems in two cases: once, where the folder for temporary files was shared in SVN, and then Texlipse caused some really nasty things during building (it first copies everything from tmp to src; then after building moves the stuff back). So, make sure, that temporary files are not shared through source control.

For the second issue, I don't know what has caused it. I copied the project in another workspace, where I got similar errors. If instead of copying locally, I did another checkout (after removing the old files entirely), the builder seemed to be working.

Comment: thanks I will have a look but our latex project is in mercurial so there is probably a problem with source control.

Comment: I see, that in the Texlipse forums (http://sourceforge.net/projects/texlipse/forums/forum/451977/topic/4719931) paalge said that the problem might be that the temp files are shared through source control, just as my first paragraph states. I think, you should look at that.

Comment: That worked, thanks for the help. Basically I had the temp folder in Mercurial.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the [answer of zoltan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7526064/41977) I've resolved my issue. I am posting for who puts his project with texlipse under versioning by dropbox and wants to use it while modifying tex files. Basically I went to project properties and I deleted temp directory name from input field labeled **Directory for Latex temporary files:**

Now it doesn't give me again errors and builds successfully.
Hope my answer is not inappropriate and it can help somebody who want to use Dropbox and not use only local directories.

Comment: In my case the "Directory for Latex temporary files: [tmp   ]" was missing. After creating this folder everything works fine. I think the dir was deletet after I clicked on "Project / Clean"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this error occured because of "cleaning" your project. Running "Project/Clean" removes the tmp folder. Running "Project / Build Project" doesn't restore that folder. Therefore this error message is thrown. The tmp folder is automatically generated (once) when a new project is created.